# TFS 2017 Plugin Issues - Caught an ExceptionTF30063: You are not authorized to access "https://tfs.com//TeamProject

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I'm trying to create a plugin in TFS 2017 ,that checks for Associated workitems before check-in and rejects the check-in if it does not meet few conditions. This was working for One Collection and One TeamProject. Now I'm trying to implement this this across multiple collections and team projects and it throws the following error "TF30063: You are not authorized to access "https://tfs.com//TeamProject" I'm pasting the code below, Please let me know what the possible issue would be .

```js
            {
                // Logic Goes here ...

                bool isNullComment = false;
                bool isDevBranchChange = false;
                bool isCodeReviewRequest = false;
                bool isCodeReviewResponse = false;
                bool isTaskAssociated = false;

                //Read all submitted items
                var changes = notification.GetSubmittedItems(requestContext);
                //Check if the changes have any DEV branch changes
                isDevBranchChange = changes.Any(change => change.ToUpper().Contains("/DEV/"));
                if (isDevBranchChange)
                {
                    isNullComment = string.IsNullOrEmpty(notification.Comment.ToString());
                    var assoWorkItems = notification.NotificationInfo.WorkItemInfo.Select(x => x.Id);  //Read all associated workitem id's                       
                    TfsTeamProjectCollection connection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(GetTfsUri(requestContext));
                    WorkItemStore wiStore = connection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

                    //check if any of associated workitem has code review
                    foreach (int id in assoWorkItems)
                    {
                        WorkItem wi = wiStore.GetWorkItem(id);
                        // Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models.WorkItem wi = witClient.GetWorkItemAsync(id).Result;

                        if (wi.Type.Name.ToUpper().Equals("CODE REVIEW REQUEST"))
                        {
                            isCodeReviewRequest = true;
                        }
                        if (wi.Type.Name.ToUpper().Equals("TASK"))
                        {
                            isTaskAssociated = true;
                        }
                        if (wi.Type.Name.ToUpper().Equals("CODE REVIEW RESPONSE"))
                        {
                            isCodeReviewResponse = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!isCodeReviewRequest || isNullComment || !isCodeReviewResponse || !isTaskAssociated)
                    {
                        statusMessage = "Check-in Rejected. Check-in Comment, Task, Code Review Request and Code Review Response workitems are Required. \nFor more information, please contact TFS Administrators: vsalm@abc.com";
                        return EventNotificationStatus.ActionDenied;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

                statusMessage = "Caught an Exception" + exception.Message;
                return EventNotificationStatus.ActionDenied;
                // Any exception, TFS will disable it. So, Log it and eat it.
                TeamFoundationApplicationCore.LogException("DecisionPoint plugin encountered the following error while processing events", exception);
            }

        }

        return EventNotificationStatus.ActionPermitted;
    }

    private Uri GetTfsUri(IVssRequestContext _requestContext)
    {

        var locationService = _requestContext.GetService<ILocationService>();
        return new Uri(locationService.GetServerAccessMapping(_requestContext).AccessPoint + "/" + _requestContext.ServiceHost.Name);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is the existing check-in policy for exactly this scenario somehow insufficient?

Comment: The same logic was working fine when i have passed credentials and collection name in the code. Now, I am trying to change the way to get TFS Connected within my code and throwing error.

Comment: Previouse (Working) logic -  `ICredentials creds = new NetworkCredential("XXXXX", "Password", "Domain");
                         TfsTeamProjectCollection connection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://tfs-ServerURL/Collection"), creds);`

Comment: I suspect you need to give the server permission to access the project collection. By default the tfs service account doesn't have access. See the docs for the TFSAggregator (and its associated code) for troubleshooting tips https://tfsaggregator.github.io/admin/troubleshooting/

Comment: I have verified again and our service account have full access on source control. Do you have any other sample for iSubscriber plugin to get TFS url and get connected with latest API (TFS 2017) ?